# Mapping two objects in Angular 7 Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a Reactive form in Angular for user registration.  The setup of the reactive form means that the form data object

[image]

is different from my viewmodel object

```
export interface RegisterViewModel {
UserName: string;
Email: string;
Password: string;
ConfirmPassword: string; }
```

To be explicit, **in the form object**, the two password properties are nested in a seprate 'matching_passwords' object.

My form object is captured in the onSubmit(value) method

```
  onSubmit(value) {
this.accountService.register(value)
.pipe(first())
.subscribe(
  data => {
    console.log('successful registration');
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  },
  error => {
    console.log('unsuccessful registration');
  }); }
```

which passes the value to the service method which expects the RegisterViewModel object.

```
  register(viewModel: RegisterViewModel) {
    return this.http.post<any>('api/Account/Register', viewModel, httpOptions)
      .pipe(map(data => {
        return data;
      }));
  }
```

Without changing my form structure so that is perfectly matches the RegisterViewModel structure, how do I map these different objects to one another?

How can I pass the form model to the register method, register(viewModel: RegisterViewModel)?  I want my RegisterViewModel to recieve the email, username, password and passwordconfirm strings from my form.

Comment: I'd like to help but I'm not sure I understood what you mean by mapping  them to one other. Could u provide an example of the result you rr aiming fir

Comment: @Koop4 How can I pass the form model to the register method: register(viewModel: RegisterViewModel), which accepts the diffrent RegisterViewModel object?  I want my RegisterViewModel to recieve the email, username, password and passwordconfirm strings from my form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply build the object from the form values. Based on your picture, that would look like:

```
// say your form value object is `form_values` (instead of `value` in your code)
const viewModelObject = <RegisterViewModel> {
  UserName: form_values.userName,
  Email: form_values.email,
  Password: form_values.matching_passwords.password,
  ConfirmPassword: form_values.matching_passwords.confirmPassword
};
```

Then you call

```
this.accountService.register(viewModelObject)
// ... following stays the same
```